# I have an issue installing Microsoft Project. How do I solve it?

Tags: windows-vista, installation, memory, microsoft-project-2007

I am trying to install Microsoft Project 2007 onto my Windows Vista. The installation process completes with no problem.

But once installed if I try to open, it says that it is configuring the Microsoft Project and later gives an error saying that there is not enough space for it to open the Microsoft Project.

This what the error says:

> There is not enough memory to complete the operation. To free up available memory, close programs, projects or windows you aren't using, and then try again.

I have tried to close all the programs, free more virtual memory but nothing works.
Can someone please explain what might be going wrong.

Comment: @sprasad12: what is the exact error message? (tip: in many error dialogs Ctrl+C to copy to the clipboard works - even though it is not listed anywhere.)

Answer (score 0):

You could be low a virtual memory.

Quit applications and retry. If that does not work, increase the virtual memory limit and restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have at least 1 GB of free disk space.

Use Disc Cleanup tool from Menu Start - Accessories (real name may be slightly different since I have a non english version of Vista). You could also use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) .

Answer (score 0):

[Service pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937154) for MS Project 2007 fixes some issues that have to do with memory, although they are not quite the same as yours, it should be worth installing before you go any further.